# Why can't I answer a question

Tags: support

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but on Math SE, I can no longer post an answer.

If I try it just comes up with "An error occured whilst submitting the answer" in red.

I can still comment and ask questions I believe, so I am confused.

Comment: It usually says why.

Comment: it seems to have sorted itself out, seems strange though, thank you!

Comment: There was a 10-15 minute period where apparently nobody could answer questions.

Comment: I see.. good to know it wasn't just me then :)

Comment: It was mentioned an meta.stackexchange too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231054/cant-submit-answers However, no real explanation given there.